# Assert that golang slices have equal elements, no matter the order

Tags: go, testing, assert

I have the following assertion in a `golang` test

```golang
us.EqualValues(testUnitMergeEnvVars[i].expectedEnvVars, gotValues)
```

where `us` is a `testify/suite.Suite` [type](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/suite#Suite).

This fails with the following message

```
expected: []envs.KeyValue{envs.KeyValue{Key:"MOO", Value:"lala"}, envs.KeyValue{Key:"KOO", Value:"Lorem\nipsum"}, envs.KeyValue{Key:"JOO", Value:"JAR"}}

actual  : []envs.KeyValue{envs.KeyValue{Key:"KOO", Value:"Lorem\nipsum"}, envs.KeyValue{Key:"MOO", Value:"lala"}, envs.KeyValue{Key:"JOO", Value:"JAR"}}
```

The slices contain the following custom type

```golang
type KeyValue struct {
    Key   string
    Value string
}
```

Given that the slices have the same elements, why does the test fail? I don't care about the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equal asserts that two objects are equal — under the hood, it’s doing a deep equal check — Slice values are considered to be deeply equal when they are both nil or both non-nil, they have the same length, and either they pint to the same initial entity of the same underlying array (that is, &a[0] == &b[0]) or their corresponding elements (up to length) are deeply equal. In your case, the order of elements differs in both expected and actual slices and the Equal check returns false. As you want to ignore the order of elements in the equal check, ElementsMatch would be the best choice here. It can be used as follows in the test suite.

```golang
type KeyValueTestSuite struct {
    suite.Suite
}

func (suite *KeyValueTestSuite) TestKeyValue() {
    expected := []envs.KeyValue{{Key: "MOO", Value: "lala"}, {Key: "KOO", Value: "Lorem\nipsum"}, {Key: "JOO", Value: "JAR"}}
    actual := []envs.KeyValue{{Key: "KOO", Value: "Lorem\nipsum"}, {Key: "MOO", Value: "lala"}, {Key: "JOO", Value: "JAR"}}
    suite.ElementsMatch(expected, actual)
}

func TestExampleTestSuite(t *testing.T) {
    suite.Run(t, new(KeyValueTestSuite))
}
```

If you still want to use EqualValues, you might need to do an explicit ordering of elements in both the slices prior to the Equal check based on the fields that you think would be ideal for your use case; this approach overkills compared to the ElementsMatch.

```golang
func (suite *KeyValueTestSuite) TestKeyValueV2() {
    expected := []envs.KeyValue{{Key: "MOO", Value: "lala"}, {Key: "KOO", Value: "Lorem\nipsum"}, {Key: "JOO", Value: "JAR"}}
    actual := []envs.KeyValue{{Key: "KOO", Value: "Lorem\nipsum"}, {Key: "MOO", Value: "lala"}, {Key: "JOO", Value: "JAR"}}

    sort.Slice(expected, func(i, j int) bool {
        return expected[i].Key < expected[j].Key
    })
    sort.Slice(actual, func(i, j int) bool {
        return actual[i].Key < actual[j].Key
    })

    suite.EqualValues(expected, actual)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the [`ElementsMatch`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert#Assertions.ElementsMatch) assertion:

> ElementsMatchf asserts that the specified listA(array, slice...) is equal
> to specified listB(array, slice...) ignoring the order of the elements. If
> there are duplicate elements, the number of appearances of each of them in
> both lists should match.